# Different behavior of sed with respect to an array and a string in the presence of backslashes

Tags: bash, sed, quoting

Let the file `foo.txt` contain

```
foo\\ bar baz 
xx
```

Why does the following correctly change "foo\\ bar" to "someotherstuff" in `foo.txt`?

```
sed -i 's/foo\\\\ bar/someotherstuff/gI' foo.txt
```

while this does not?

```
a=("foo\\\\ bar") 
b=(someotherstuff) 

for ((i=0;i<${#a[@]};++i)); do 
    sed -i "s/${a[i]}/${b[i]}/gI" foo.txt 
done
```

They are supposed to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

`man bash` explains the perils of using double-quotes:

> ```
>    Enclosing  characters  in  double  quotes pre‐
>    serves the literal  value  of  all  characters
>    within the quotes, with the exception of $, `,
>    \, and, when history expansion is enabled,  !.
>    The  characters  $  and ` retain their special
>    meaning within double quotes.   The  backslash
>    retains its special meaning only when followed
>    by one of the following characters: $,  `,  ",
>    \, or <newline>.  A double quote may be quoted
>    within double quotes by preceding  it  with  a
>    backslash.  If enabled, history expansion will
>    be performed unless an !  appearing in  double
>    quotes  is  escaped  using  a  backslash.  The
>    backslash preceding the !  is not removed.
> ```

In other words, use double-quotes around a bash variable when you want bash to process dollar-signs, backquotes, backslashes and exclamation points.

When you want a string to sed passed to sed unmangled, use single-quotes, as in your first example.  `man bash` explains:

> ```
>    Enclosing  characters  in  single  quotes pre‐
>    serves the literal  value  of  each  character
>    within  the  quotes.   A  single quote may not
>    occur between single quotes,  even  when  pre‐
>    ceded by a backslash.
> ```

In sum, there are two alternatives.  One uses single-quotes when defining `a`:

```
$ a=('foo\\\\ bar')
$ b=(someotherstuff)
$ sed  "s/${a[0]}/${b[0]}/gI" foo.txt
someotherstuff baz 
xxx
```

and the second uses double-quotes when defining `a`:

```
$ a=("foo\\\\\\\\ bar")
$ sed  "s/${a[0]}/${b[0]}/gI" foo.txt
someotherstuff baz 
xxx
```

The latter requires eight backslashes.  Because you want to replace two backslashes, you have to provide sed with four backslashes.  To provide sed with four, you have to provide bash, when using double-quotes, with eight.

Comment: So I should do `a=('foo\\\\ bar')`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha sed needs four backslashes.  So, you must supply 8 to bash: `a=("foo\\\\\\\\ bar")`.

Comment: Ok, But is `a=('foo\\\\ bar')` an alternative?

Comment: @FaheemMitha  Oops.  Sorry.  Yes, `a=('foo\\\\ bar')` works also.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=("foo\\\\ bar")
```

yields as a value for `${a[0]}`:

```
"foo\\ bar"
```

which is what is getting sent to `sed`, which then searches for:

```
"foo\ bar"
```

which does not match any lines in its input.

Comment: Why does it do that? Backslash escaping again? So, we have to do eight backslashes?

Comment: Indeed, because backslashes are escapes for pretty much everything, you need to escape them for each thing that is going to be reading the backslashes.  Also, keep in mind that `"\\\\"` is different from `'\\\\'`.